# Distribution of relative proportions of draws from two uniform distributions?

Tags: distributions, uniform-distribution, distribution-identification

Drawing samples from 2 uniform distributions and calculating pairwise proportions of drawn values gives rise to a distribution I cannot recognize. What distribution is this?

```r
    set.seed(13)
    abundances1 <- runif(n = 1000000)
    abundances2 <- runif(n = 1000000)
    
    proportions <- mapply(function(x, y){
      x / (x + y)
    }, abundances1, abundances2)
    
    hist(proportions, breaks = 10000)
```

[image]

Comment: For $1/2 \le x \le 1,$ compute $\Pr(U/(U+V)\le x)$ for iid uniform variables $U,V$ (it's easy) to obtain the CDF, then differentiate w.r.t. $x$ for the density.

Comment: Incidentally, the logarithm (suitably defined) of a version of this random variable has a logistic distribution. The "right" definition is $\log(U-V)-\log(U+V)$ when $U \gt V$ and $-(\log(-(U-V))-\log(U+V))$ otherwise.